# delphi array of array of PByte

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers

I have a function inside of an unmodifyable DLL that wants a @buffer passed with PBYTE.

```
function Base(Buffer: PBYTE): Integer;
```

On top of it I have my buffers with different lengths.
Now I want to create something that works like an Array holding all of these buffers for easier accessibility (an Index is required). I tried turning it every which way, but I'm in a mental dead end.

```
Buffer1: array[0..100] of Byte;
Buffer2: array[250..600] of Byte;

Buffers: array of PByte;
```

came closest to working, with the problem on usage in my other functions now trying to accept

```
function Foo(var Buffer: PByte): Boolean;
begin
    Result := Boolean(Buffer[SomePosition]);
end;
```

throwing
    "Array-Type required".

I turned the whole structure upside down interchanging Pointers, Arrays of Pointers introduced with my own types or creating an Array of Array of PByte, which leads to issues with my naturally inconsistent array lengths. I can't solve it.

## Edit: The details

```
buffers : array of PByte;
buffer_DB11 : array[0..200] of byte;
buffer_DB20 : array[400..640] of byte;

function ReadInt(var Buffer : array of Byte; Position : Word): Integer;
begin
  Result := buffer[Position]*256+buffer[Position+1];
end;

procedure TServiceItem.FetchValues;   // somewhere else
begin
    Value := IntToStr( ReadInt( buffers[db], Position) );
end;
```

I hope that can make clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `Result := buffer[Position]*256+buffer[Position+1];` would mean that the integer is stored in big-endian 16-bit format. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: I removed my answer because your question makes no sense and my attempts to communicate with you proved to be fruitless.

Comment: It is still not clear what is happening. Obviously, `Foo` is not the real name, and it has a different signature as well. Show your real code, e.g. how you call the DLL function, and the real declaration of the DLL function. With "real" I mean copied and pasted from your code.

Comment: Somehow this reminds me a little of some CHIP-8 emulator source code I have seen recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the unmodifiable DLL comes into it, so going off your edit you seem to assume that PByte and array of byte are the same thing. They are not.

buffers[ xxx] is of type PByte not array of byte, so either you need to cast or modify your function to take a PByte.

```
buffers : array of PByte;
buffer_DB11 : array[0..200] of byte;
buffer_DB20 : array[400..640] of byte;

function ReadInt(var Buffer : PByte; Position : Word): Integer;
begin
  Result := buffer[Position]*256+buffer[Position+1];
end;

procedure TServiceItem.FetchValues;   // somewhere else
begin
    Value := IntToStr( ReadInt( buffers[db], Position) );
end;
```

Comment: You need pointer arithmetic enabled for that code to compile and why use a variety param? I don't think the question is remotely clear yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, but he needs pointer arithmetic enabled for any of it to work, and that part is his code, not mine. Hopefully this will trigger some response from him as he seems to have some difficulty understanding what we need to help him. At the very least it addresses what appears to be a very fundamental misunderstanding of how Delphi works.

Comment: I already answered but deleted when the ensuing comments were utterly confused.

Comment: Oh - I see. I didn't see your original answer (or the ensuing comments). Sorry. Was it fundamentally the same reply? If so I will delete, since it is likely to be unhelpful.

Comment: I don't have opinion on that. I just think that like I was, you are just wasting your time here. Sadly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. OK, thanks for the heads up. I will leave it up for now and see what (if anything) happens.

Comment: Basically this is the answer. The DLL function takes only a PByte to start writing, which is imho a really poor interface choice after all. It turned out that I could not really use any general OO handling structure on top of it, because the DLL writes Bytes blindly starting from PByte, which means TArray<Byte> will be corrupted, dynamic arrays generally. The only thing I can point the dll to are fixed size array's of Byte, which means it all boils down to passing PByte's all throughout the structure.